# $A.run() is deprecated what is the impact on existing code

Tags: lightning-aura-components, summer-16

The recent lightning developer guide (version-37) states that
"$A.run() is deprecated. Use $A.getCallback() instead".
Is this going to impact our existing implementation. Do we need to change all the $A.run() references in our code to $A.getCallback() before moving to Summer'16.
Can anyone explain what would be the impact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. You need to change them when the LockerService critical update is applied.

The critical update will be applied as follows, according to the [Summer '16 release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_lightning_locker.htm):

> LockerService is automatically enabled for:
>
> - New orgs created after the Summer ’16 release
> - All Developer Edition orgs
> - All existing orgs with no custom Lightning components
>
> If you don't see this critical update in your org, LockerService has been
>   automatically enabled. Automatic enablement occurs within 24 hours
>   after the release.

If it is not auto applied or applied manually by you, it will be applied automatically on Oct 16, 2016 (according to the date I see in the org).

You can verify it and do your own testing in a [Summer '16 pre-release org](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-summer16.jsp) if you don't have access to a Summer '16 org yet.

If you use $A.run after the LockerService critical update has been applied you'll get an error that $A.run does not exist.
[image: $A.run does not exist]

It is the [aura-api rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_rules_aura_api.htm) that disallows the use of the $A.run method. You can see the actual rules file used by the Salesforce Lightning CLI linting tool after you [install the Salesforce Lightning CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_installation.htm) at ~/.heroku/node_modules/salesforce-lightning-cli/rules/aura-api.js and see $A.run is not whitelisted. And, if you were to run the tool you'd get an `Invalid Aura API` error.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this @Peter. So as I understand from your answer $A.run() should run fine, if I don't install the LoskerService update (for time being). And of course I will have to remove all the $A.run() references by Winter'17 release. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can double check the date that update will be auto-installed in your org in the critical updates section of your org from the setup menu.

Answer (score 4):

Excellent answer PeterK! I'm going to build off your ps and add that even without Locker which does not excuse that method on SecureAura - it's been deprecated for multiple releases - but the bigger issue is "why" it was removed in the first place: access= visibility checks. $A.getCallback() is the replacement for $A.run() and it does something very important that $A.run() cannot do - it remembers the context of who sets up the callback and restores the context before invoking the callback at a later time. If you use $A.run() inside of a non Lightning managed JavaScript callback - say from a manually wired up addEventListener() you will run into access check violations when trying to use components, events, attributes, from your own namespace. These will look like "undefined does not have access to blah". The undefined part f the error is because of that lack of context restoration. Code that is invoked outside of the Lightning component lifecycle will be impacted by this.

Gopal can you give specifics about where you are using $A.run()? In many many cases I have seen this being used when it's not actually needed anymore. We are also looking at automatically wrapping with $A.getCallback() in a future release (Locker makes this a possibility!).

Comment: Thanks for providing more details @Doug, In our case we have some manually wired Jquery event listeners in which we refer component and some attributes, and these event listeners get executed outside of Lightning component lifecycle. So to avoid any possible access related issues we have enclosed the logic by a $A.run() and cmp.IsValid check.

Comment: related to the LockerService can we expect JQuery lower versions not supported  issue to be resolved by winter'17 release, as the LockerService will be auto-enabled for all orgs when Winter ‘17 is out. Could you confirm this as our future development is dependent on this.

Comment: JQuery 1.12.4 should be working with Locker already - please open a case with specific details if you are seeing issues and let me know the case ID so I can follow up.

Comment: $A.run() will not help with access= at all - the scenario you describe requires $A.getCallback()

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Doug. we were suggested to use $A.run() in an office hour anyhow we will change it to $A.getCallback() now. Also really exited about the automatic wrapping with $A.getCallback() in a future releases. Thank you very much.